# Is "crawling out of your skin" an idiom?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found this sentence in a book about anxiety and how to treat it, but I don't understant the meaning of this expression. Is it an idiom?

> “Doesn’t everyone feel like they want to **crawl out of their skin** at
>   times?”

There are further rethorical questions in the same context: “Isn’t everyone struggling to get a good night’s sleep and wake well-rested?” "Well, doesn’t everyone get shakiness in their hands before a first date?”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Books claims 2,850 hits for [***crawl out of my skin***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22crawl+out+of+my+skin%22), so I guess that's common enough to say it's an "idiom". I doubt many if any of those hits are *literal* usages (a Wild West trapper waking up and crawling out of the bearskin he slept in, for example). It just means *to feel so (psychologically) uncomfortable that you wish your conscious mind could somehow escape / slink away from your body*.

<sub>(answer transcribed from comment)</sub>